# Why isn't my "yield" working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delay, yield, coroutine

i'm very new to programming and i have a feeling that there is a very stupid mistake here. But can anyone explain me, why instead of 4 messages with a delay of 2 seconds between, i instantaniously get the last message shown only.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Wait : MonoBehaviour {

    private int i = 0;
    public string[] message;

    [SerializeField]
    private Text toText;

    public IEnumerator Message(float waitTime)
    {
        toText.text = message[i];
        i++;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime = 2f);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Message(i));
        StartCoroutine(Message(i));
        StartCoroutine(Message(i));
        StartCoroutine(Message(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: The keyword makes your method to be deferredly executed. Thus it is only executed when calling `Enumerator.MoveNext()`, which you never call (to do so use a `for`-loop for example).

Comment: @HimBromBeere isn't that the job of `StartCoroutine` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(Message(i));
    StartCoroutine(Message(i));
    StartCoroutine(Message(i));
    StartCoroutine(Message(i));
}
```

I don't think that is doing what you think it should. This will not wait for each `StartCoroutine` to finish and will call the next `StartCoroutine`.

This is what happens:

The first `StartCoroutine(Message(i));` call will start the `Message` function. 
Once it meets the `yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime = 2f);` line of code, it will then jump back into the `Start()` function.

The next `StartCoroutine(Message(i));` will be called then the-same thing will happen again.

When calling a coroutine function from a non coroutine function, as long as you have `yield return new WaitForSeconds`, `yield return null;`, or `yield return` what-ever `YieldInstruction` is implemented, the execution will return to that non coroutine function in-which the `StartCoroutine` function was called from and continue to execute other code.

To make coroutine wait for another one to finish, make the  `StartCoroutine(Message(i));` function call from another coroutine function. This will allow you to `yield` each coroutine function call. This is called chaining coroutine.

To chain or `yield` a coroutine function call, simply put `yield return` in front of the `StartCoroutine` function. `yield return StartCoroutine(Message(i));`

```
public class Wait : MonoBehaviour {
    private int i = 0;
    public string[] message;

    [SerializeField]
    private Text toText;

    public IEnumerator Message(float waitTime)
    {
        // toText.text = message[i];
        i++;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime = 2f);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(startMessage());
    }

    IEnumerator startMessage()
    {
        yield return StartCoroutine(Message(i));//Wait until this coroutine function retuns
        yield return StartCoroutine(Message(i));//Wait until this coroutine function retuns
        yield return StartCoroutine(Message(i));//Wait until this coroutine function retuns
        yield return StartCoroutine(Message(i));//Wait until this coroutine function retuns
    }
}
```

Now, each `StartCoroutine(Message(i));` call will wait until the first one finishes. You can always use a `boolean` variable to do this but it is much better to `yield` the `StartCoroutine` call.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the text is set instantly is because `StartCoroutine` will execute the enumerator from `Message`.

The first two things that happen is setting the text and incrementing `i`. Only after that is done, you will yield the `WaitForSeconds`. It is at that point `StartCoroutine` will pause further execution of `Message`.

If you had had a line after the `yield return` you would have seen the effects of that after the 2 seconds.

in the example in the docs you can also see the behavior after the `yield return Wait`
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html

I would suggest running the next test to become more familiar with how yield return works:

```
IEnumerator MessageOuter() {
    Console.WriteLine("outer 1");
    var inner = MessageInner();
    Console.WriteLine("outer 2");
    return inner;
}
IEnumerator MessageInner() {
    Console.WriteLine("inner 1");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    Console.WriteLine("inner 2");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    Console.WriteLine("inner 3");
}
void Start() {
    Console.WriteLine("start 1");
    var outer = MessageOuter();
    Console.WriteLine("start 2");
    StartCoroutine(outer);
    Console.WriteLine("start 3");
}
```